# Pass data from a hook to (be used in another hook)

Tags: commerce, hooks

So in a hook `hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh()` I make some calculations that I would later like to use in a different hook `hook_form_alter`, how can I pass these data/object and use later on?

In that first hook, I have a `EntityMetadataWrapper` but it seems I can only give it data that actually is persisted, and mine should only exist for the request.

Again, I could use `$_SESSION` but that storage is used for persistent storage through multiple requests. And I'm not looking for that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the above is a slight variation, same answer as @Clive, except Clive created a function to retrieve the drupal static stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, there's no mechanism to pass data from one arbitrary function to another (which is what two separate hooks essentially are). You'll have to make the data available another way.

Drupal uses a pattern like this all over the place:

```
function MYMODULE_get_data() {
  $data = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, NULL);

  if (!$data) {
    $data = some_function_to_build_data();
  }

  return $data;
}

function MYMODULE_commerce_cart_order_refresh(...) {
  // Get the data, populating it if it doesn't already exist.
  $data = MYMODULE_get_data();
}

function MYMODULE_form_alter(...) {
  // Retrieve the data.
  $data = MYMODULE_get_data();
}
```

That's a contrived example, it'll make more sense when you plug your own requirements into it.

Comment: `drupal_static()` is the first thing I can think of as well....